# How to Update a single form using JPA Query

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I need help please.I am updating a single field in my database but i am not very good using JPA Query. I am still learning though.

```
@Entity
public class CertificateProgramme {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Long id;

        @NotNull(message = "The above field must not be blank.")
        @Pattern(regexp="[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\."
                +"[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@"
                +"(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?",
                message="Please enter a valid email address")
        private String email;

        private boolean flag;
```

i want to update the flag field to false. I am able to update when i am using the save method in the serviceImpl class but it does not work when i try it without the save.

I define the method unFlagger`(CertificateProgramme certificateProgramme)` in the service interface to be implemented in ServiceImpl

```
public interface CertificateService {
    List<CertificateProgramme> findAll();
    CertificateProgramme ListAll();
    CertificateProgramme findOne(Long id);
    void save(CertificateProgramme certificateProgramme);
    CertificateProgramme flagger(CertificateProgramme certificateProgramme);
    CertificateProgramme unFlagger(CertificateProgramme certificateProgramme);
}
```

ServiceImpl.java

```
 @Override
public CertificateProgramme flag(CertificateProgramme certificateProgramme) {
    certificateDao.unFlagger(certificateProgramme);
    return certificateProgramme;
}
```

Dao.java

```
@Repository
public interface CertificateDao extends CrudRepository<CertificateProgramme, Long> {
    @Query("select t from CertificateProgramme t where t.user.id=?#{principal.id}")
    List<CertificateProgramme> findAll();
    @Query("select t from CertificateProgramme t where t.user.id=?#{principal.id}")
    CertificateProgramme ListAll();
```

I need help here please

```
@Modifying
@Query("update CertificateProgramme ear set ear.flag = ?#{'FALSE'} where ear.user.id=?#{principal.id}")
CertificateProgramme unFlagger(CertificateProgramme flag);
```

Controller

This is supposed to update the flag field but it is not updating. I am rather getting an error.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "cert_prog/{certId}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String UpdateFlag(@PathVariable Long certId, CertificateProgramme certificateProgramme){
        certificateService.unFlagger(certificateProgramme);
        return String.format("redirect:/cert_prog/%s/edit", certId);
    }
```

Error

```
    2017-02-25 21:40:28.257 ERROR 20769 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Executing an update/delete query; nested exception is javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query] with root cause

javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractQueryImpl.executeUpdate(AbstractQueryImpl.java:71) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$ModifyingExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:238) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.9.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:78) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.9.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:100) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.9.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at or
```

Comment: You didn't call `CertificateDao.unFlagger` method from any place, so your modifying query wasn't triggered. Call it either from controller or service method.

Comment: Hi @JakubCh. can you help me with the update query. I can't figure out how to set a field to a string like @Query("update CertificateProgramme ear set ear.flag = 'false' where ear.user.id=?#{principal.id}")

Comment: Hi @JakubCh. i added it to my service. It's gives me an error. It wants to validate all the fields. i Just need to update just one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should fix your dao method. If you want query that modify one field of distinct entity pass only that field value and entity id to method as parameters (or even id only, if you want your method always set flag to false). Then reference to them in query in proper JPQL format. Example of such case can be found in [spring data JPA documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.modifying-queries)

In your case it should looks like this:

**CertificateDAO.java**

```
@Modifying
@Query("update CertificateProgramme ear set ear.flag = FALSE where ear.id = ?1")
int unFlagger(Long id);
```

**ServiceImpl.java**

```
@Override
public CertificateProgramme flag(CertificateProgramme certificateProgramme) {
    certificateDao.unFlagger(certificateProgramme.getId());
    return findOne(certificateProgramme.getId());
}
```

This one should work. You could probably also get rid of passing CertificateProgramme to service and pass only the id.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help and documentation. This worked 
public CertificateProgramme flag(CertificateProgramme certificateProgramme) {
    certificateDao.unFlagger(certificateProgramme.getId());
   return certificateProgramme;
}